# How to remove a string in limits.conf with ansible pam_limits module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm configuring `/etc/security/limits.conf` with Ansible' new module [pam_limits](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pam_limits_module.html#pam-limits).

What I've succeeded at:

- Setting values for specific domain and type in the default `limits.conf`. (A new string is appended to the end of the file).
- Changing values (the string gets rewritten).

The problem is when I want to completely remove the setting. E.g. I don't want to save core dumps anymore. **How should I use pam_limits to remove the string completely?**

I've managed to develop the following workaround, but I don't consider it good. It doesn't remove the string but rather sets the limit to 0, which may be not the same.

**roles/myrole/tasks/main.yaml**

```
...
- name: enable core dumps for myservice
  pam_limits: domain='*' limit_type='-' limit_item=core value="{{ 'unlimited' if myrole_save_core_dumps else 0 }}"
...
```

**group_vars/myhosts.yaml:**

```
myrole_save_core_dumps: true
```

**myservice.yaml**

```
hosts: myhosts
become: yes
roles: 
  - myrole
```

Comment: AFAIK, in 2022 we still don't have a way to remove a inserted line with `community.general.pam_limits` completely, and I don't find any feature request on the new repos (please correct me if I'm wrong). Seems we would be better with a simple template file to put in the `pam_limits.d` dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would be an feature which is currently not implemented. But there is a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/1083) on github for this feature.